# Unable to free allocated memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

I'm a beginner in C and I have this problem where I `malloc/calloc` two-dimensional arrays and get errors when trying to `free` them after use. The programs fills square matrices with random values and lets the user choose between different functions to multiply them, in order to evaluate performance. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <assignment2.h> // declares my non-blas multiplication functions

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

   int n, i, j, blockSize, choice;

   printf("Enter n: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("Enter block size: ");
   scanf("%d", &blockSize);

   do {
      printf("Enter method (1 -> naive, 2 -> ijk-blocked, " 
            "3 -> kij-blocked, 4 -> cblas_dgemm): ");
      scanf("%d", &choice);
   } while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);

   double **a, **b, **result;

   /* Init matrices*/
   a = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
   b = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
   result = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
   if (a == NULL || b == NULL || result == NULL) {
      printf("Error.\n");
      return 1;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      *(a + i) = malloc(n* sizeof(double));
      *(b + i) = malloc(n* sizeof(double));
      *(result + i) = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
   }

   fillMatrix(n, a);
   fillMatrix(n, b);

   // timing
   struct timeval tv1, tv2;
   struct timezone tz;
   gettimeofday(&tv1, &tz);

   switch(choice) {
      case 1:
         printf("matmul_ijk\n");
         matmul_ijk(n, a, b, result);
         break;
      case 2:
         printf("matmul_ijk_blocked\n");
         matmul_ijk_blocked(n, blockSize, a, b, result);
         break;
      case 3:
         printf("matmul_kij_blocked\n");
         matmul_kij_blocked(n, blockSize, a, b, result);
         break;
      case 4:
         printf("cblas_dgemm\n");
         cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, n, n, n, 1.0,
               a[0], n, b[0], n, 0.0, result[0], n);
         break;
      default:
         puts("Error. Mode not recognized.");
   }
   gettimeofday(&tv2, &tz);

   // Print time
   double elapsed = (double) (tv2.tv_sec-tv1.tv_sec) 
      + (double) (tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec) * 1.e-6;
   printf("Time elapsed: %lf\n", elapsed);

   // for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      // free(a[i]);
      // free(b[i]);
      // free(result[i]);
   // }
   // free(a);
   // free(b);
   // free(result);
   return 0;
}
```

Now at the very end I commented out my attempts to free the memory I had previously allocated. Because if I enable the last three calls to `free`, I'm getting errors of the sort

```
2(724,0x7fff7cc76960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe62a016000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and I don't know why, since I did allocate the memory myself. But the program runs normally and delivers the result, it's only on freeing that the error happens.
Interestingly, this happens **only** when `n` is large. For e.g. `n=1000` there is no issue, but for `n=2000` there is. For speed reasons I always choose the `BLAS`routine to test this, I don't know if the others display the same behaviour.

So I'm guessing I'm missing something important here since

1. Memory `malloc`ed by me does not seem to want to be `free`d
2. The problem appears to be related to the size of the matrix and I don't get how.

Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: Are you running out of memory when `n` is large? Try checking the single pointers in your initial `for` loop for `NULL`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are representing this with two dimensional arrays? It's fine to do so but its also introduces more complexity where a single dimensional array would do just fine.

Comment: It seems to me that the error is in one of the functions manipulating the arrays. As Casper Von B said, using two dimensional arrays introduces more complexity. Maybe you inadvertently replace one of the arrays (a[i]) by a value or something like that. Did you check if the results of the algorithms are correct? Did you check if the error appears with every choice in your switch? How do you know the problem is related to the size of the matrix?

Comment: Wild guess, you are performing pointer arithmetic somewhere where you intended to just do arithmetic.

Comment: Your `for` loop does not check if those `malloc`'s fail. You should really add some error check there also.

Comment: If I did run out of memory, it would be expected that this will be revealed during the attempt to multiply he arrays, wouldn't it? But the multiply succeeds (though I did not check correctness yet for n>10). @Casper: the reason for 2d-arrays is that it's easier to program, otherwise I would have to do some more calculations to get the right indices during loops. In general I don't think the function call itself is the problem. This is BLAS after all, not something I cooked up myself. I shall do some more error checking and experiments this evening, hopefully I'll have more information then.

Comment: @consternate "If I did run out of memory, it would be expected that this will be revealed during the attempt to multiply he arrays"  No.  You _may_ receive some sort of run-time failure.  You may not.  In C, practicing safe-memory access is the program's responsibility.  Use protection - check that your allocations are good.  (Note: suspect your real issue though is in your un-posted functions.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I did find the problem, although no explanation why things go wrong. The way I allocated the arrays `a`, `b` and `result` was wrong since the rows were not consecutive in memory, but could be anywhere. `dgemm`expects them to be consecutive though. Thus, I changed the program to first allocate the whole matrices and then let the individual row pointers point evenly spaced into that block. That worked. However, I don't understand what `dgemm`does to my pointers with the effect outlined above, as I'm still freeing what I myself have allocated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following code without incident for values of `n` that included 1000 and 2000:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    int n, i;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    double **a, **b, **result;

    /* Init matrices*/
    a = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
    b = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
    result = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
    if (a == NULL || b == NULL || result == NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(a + i) = malloc(n* sizeof(double));
        *(b + i) = malloc(n* sizeof(double));
        *(result + i) = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
        free(b[i]);
        free(result[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps there is something going on with the functions which manipulate `a`, `b` and `result`. For one, if you are multiplying two two-dimensional arrays and putting the end result into a variable called `result`, your multiplication function should probably be taking a triple pointer to `result`, e.g.:

```
/* allocate space for a, b and result... */
foo(a, b, &result);
/* do something with result... */
```

You might double-check your function signatures and code.

If you are using `gcc`, compile your code with the `-Wall` warning set:

```
$ gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo.bin
```

Also perhaps consider using the `gdb` debugger to find out where the crash is occurring exactly and what values your data are holding at that time. I'm not an expert in it and I find [RMS's tutorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/) to be a useful resource to come back to.

Comment: Could you clarify why I should use a triple pointer for this? I'm only manipulating the entries of the matrices, I don't want to modify the values referenced by any other pointer. Also, as I'm using BLAS, I have to stick to the right signature which says the argument must be 'pointer to double'.